# CPU hits %100 when a property of an object is set by two other objects at the same time

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm dealing with a particularly nasty bug that causes the main thread to hit %100 and the UI freezes completely.

In essence, this is a "simulation" where 100 node instances are created as "cells" and 2 other nodes as an attacker and defender.  The cells have two properties, addiction and annoyance, which are modified by the attacker and defender every second.

I run a timer that calls fire() method on each of the attackers and defender, passing a randomly picked cell as an argument.

The fire() method in the attacker will calculate it's own power based on time T which is the time elapsed since the launch of the simulation and call the increaseAddiction() and increaseAnnoyance() methods on the passed cells, passing it's calculated power. The same thing will happen with the defender cell's fire() method but this time decreaeAddiction() and decreaseAnnoyance() methods are called.

The power calcution is not a linear function, and is different on the attacker and the defender creating moments of dominance, for the attacker or the defender. The cell nodes are colored according to their addicton and annoyance levels, making it an interesting animation.

The problem appears after some time T after the simulation has started running. I was able to single out the "self.annoyanceLevel = newLevel" line as the culprut, when removed the code does not show this behaviour. 
Also, the issue does not happen when fire() methods are removed from the attacker or the defender, which led me to suspect a race condition so I tried to call these in turns instead of calling them the same time but this did not help. I tried to create a new dispatch queue and call them from there but did not help. I tried to create a lock/unlock mechanism by flagging the cell as "inUse" until the setAnnoyance() returns but it did not help, I tried to que the changes by adding them to an array and calling the setAnnoyanceLevels() sperately to use the values in the que array but it did not help.  I was not able to find anything like division by zero, or other logical probelms such as accidental infinite loops.

I tried to to hardcode the value that causes the issue(apparently it hangs when it's changed from 63 to 100) and this fixed the problem, however, this does not help me as I do not need a hardcoded number.

Here are the simplified versions of the functions

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.2, target: self, selector: #selector(fireAtCells), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


 /* The methods that run the simulation */
 @objc func fireAtCells(){

         for bot in  GameEngine().data.attackBots{

            var targetCells =  GameEngine().data.cells.filter { cell in
                return cell.addictionLevel < 100
            }


                let pickedCell = Int.random(in: 0 ... targetCells.count - 1)


                bot.fire(cell: targetCells[pickedCell])
            }
        }
          for bot in  GameEngine().data.defenceBots{

                var targetCells =  GameEngine().data.cells.filter { cell in
                    return cell.addictionLevel > 0 || cell.annoyanceLevel > 0
                }


                    let pickedCell = Int.random(in: 0 ... targetCells.count - 1)


                    bot.fire(cell: targetCells[pickedCell])
                }
            }


    }

 /* These are the methods on the attacker and defender that calculate the power etc. and increaseAddicton  or decreaseAnnoyance, decreaseAddiction methods on the Cells */

 func fire(cell: Cell){

     let gameStatus = GameEngine()

    let pickBullet = Int.random(in: 0 ... bullets.count - 1)
    let bullet = bullets[pickBullet]

        switch bullet {
        case .addict:
            cell.decreaseAnnoyance(50)
            cell.increaseAddiction(Int(gameStatus.status.attackPower))
            bulletColor = .red
        case .annoy:
            let power = Int(gameStatus.status.attackPower)
            cell.increaseAnnoyance(power)

        }


}

 /* The methods in the Cell objects that adjust it's own properties when called from the attacker or defender, addiction methods are pretty much the same, so ommiting them */

 func increaseAnnoyance(_ power: Int){
     self.setAnnoyanceLevel(power + self.annoyanceLevel)
 }
 func decreaseAnnoyance(_ power: Int){
     self.setAnnoyanceLevel(self.annoyanceLevel - power)
 }



 func setAnnoyanceLevel(_ level : Int){

        let newLevel = (level > 100) ? 100 : (level < 1 ? 1 : level)

        self.annoyanceLevel = newLevel 


        self.wiggle(interval: 0.5 - 0.004 * Double(level), strength: 20)
        self.colorize(color: UIColor.yellow, level: level)

    }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Update:**  I was able to intercept the execution just before the CPU hits %100, and it looks like the Timer misbehaves. After the increaseAnnoyance() returns and the timer prepares to fire the FireAtCells() method it somehow gets stuck at an infinite loop. On the last loop before %100 issue I can see that the Timer object never actually finishes initialization and doesn't call the ForeAtCells method, instead it gets stuck.

**Update 2** Okay, strangly enough, the timer never finishes executing the last time but the %100 CPU seems to be caused by a timer used by some SKAction on the Spritekit nodes. SpriteKit Actions never access these properties, I don't understand why the issue is only caused when the object property is changed programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try,  if eliminates your double looping, and removes timer:

```
let action = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.run{fireAtCells()},SKAction.wait(forDuration:0.2)]))
scene.run(action)


/* The methods that run the simulation */
@objc func fireAtCells(){
    var attackTargetCells =  GameEngine().data.cells.filter { cell in
        return cell.addictionLevel < 100
    }
    for bot in  GameEngine().data.attackBots{
        let pickedCell = attackTargetCells[Int.random(in: 0 ... attackTargetCells.count - 1)]
        bot.fire(cell: pickedCell)
        if pickedCell.addictionLevel >= 100 { 
            attackTargetCells.remove(pickedCell)
        }
    }
    let defenceTargetCells =  GameEngine().data.cells.filter { cell in
        return cell.addictionLevel > 0 || cell.annoyanceLevel > 0
    }
    for bot in  GameEngine().data.defenceBots{
        let pickedCell = defenseTargetCells[Int.random(in: 0 ... defenseTargetCells.count - 1)]
        bot.fire(cell: pickedCell)
        if cell.addictionLevel <= 0 || cell.annoyanceLevel <= 0 {
            defenseTargetCells.remove(pickedCell)
        }
    }
}

 /* These are the methods on the attacker and defender that calculate the power etc. and increaseAddicton  or decreaseAnnoyance, decreaseAddiction methods on the Cells */

func fire(cell: Cell){
    let gameStatus = GameEngine()
    let pickBullet = Int.random(in: 0 ... bullets.count - 1)
    let bullet = bullets[pickBullet]
        switch bullet {
        case .addict:
            cell.decreaseAnnoyance(50)
            cell.increaseAddiction(Int(gameStatus.status.attackPower))
            bulletColor = .red
        case .annoy:
            let power = Int(gameStatus.status.attackPower)
            cell.increaseAnnoyance(power)

        }
}

 /* The methods in the Cell objects that adjust it's own properties when called from the attacker or defender, addiction methods are pretty much the same, so ommiting them */

 func increaseAnnoyance(_ power: Int){
     self.setAnnoyanceLevel(power + self.annoyanceLevel)
 }
 func decreaseAnnoyance(_ power: Int){
     self.setAnnoyanceLevel(self.annoyanceLevel - power)
 }



 func setAnnoyanceLevel(_ level : Int){
     let newLevel = (level > 100) ? 100 : (level < 1 ? 1 : level)
     self.annoyanceLevel = newLevel 
     self.wiggle(interval: 0.5 - 0.004 * Double(level), strength: 20)
     self.colorize(color: UIColor.yellow, level: level)
 }
```